# two buttons, like and hate colors toggling. I don't understand why colors won't be changed with my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons, love and hate. when love is clicked it should change its color and when hate is clicked it should change its color. They should toggle colors. I have a fiddle here;https://jsfiddle.net/2wLvveqo/3/
can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
        <div class="panel-footer">
<span class="thumb" style="padding-right:7px;"><a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>love</a></span>   
<span class="thumb"><a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>hate</a></span>
<span style="float:right;">
<span class="time_presentation">{{ post.pub_date | date }}</span>
    {{ post.moderator.user }} submit <i class="fa fa-eye"> {{ post.views }}
</i></span>

</div>


var toggle = false;
$(".thumb a").click(function(e){
    var target =$(e.target); e.preventDefault();
  if(target.data("change")){
        target.css({ color:"red"});
  }else{
        var thumb = $(".thumb [data-change]");
      thumb.css({color:"blue"})
  }
  return false;
})
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this if(target.data("change")){..}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using simple `if` condition. `.text()` will return `textContent` of the target element.

```js
$(".thumb a").click(function(e) {
  var target = $(e.target);
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.vote').removeClass('red blue')
  if (target.text() == 'love') {
    target.addClass('red');
  } else {
    target.addClass('blue');
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-footer">
  <span class="thumb" style="padding-right:7px;"><a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>love</a></span>
  <span class="thumb"><a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>hate</a></span>
  <span style="float:right;">
<span class="time_presentation">{{ post.pub_date | date }}</span> {{ post.moderator.user }} submit <i class="fa fa-eye"> {{ post.views }}
</i>
  </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using data attribute but you had never set it into the html. First of all set the initial data attribute to the html and will work.

`target.data("change")` is always giving undefined and which is false in JavaScript so `target.css({ color:"red"})` never get executed.

and

`$(".thumb [data-change]")` is always giving empty so `thumb.css({color:"blue"})` have not effect on any dom element.

Regards